# Nested promise in a for loop not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I am having trouble extending a `Promise` inside a `.then()`. I am trying to perform DB updates in a for-loop and then close the database after all records are processed. However the application exits with `process.exit()` right away which means that `process.exit()` was executed even before all db updates were finished. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with the nested promise.

```
var myDB;

function doSomething() {
   return MongoClient.connect(DB_CONNECTION).then(function(db) {
        myDB = db;
        var collection = db.collection(COLLETION_NAME);
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            promise.then(function{
                collection.update({
                   symbol: items[i].symbol
                }, {
                   $set: { 
                      value: 123
                   }
                }, {
                   upsert: true
               });  
            });
        }
   })
}

var promise = doSomething();
promise.then(function(){
    console.log("DONE");
    myDB.close();
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Well the function is `function doSomething(promise)` and you're calling it like `var promise = doSomething()` without passing any promise. Another thing is that inside your db callback `function(db)` you **do not return promise** nor any kind of result, therefore it cannot be chained.

Comment: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @AndreyPopov thanks for the comment. I understand that I am doing something wrong, the problem is I am having trouble fixing it. How do I change it to return a promise within a for loop?

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks for pointing me to the right direction

Comment: @MarkPazon, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code as per @RayonDabre 's suggestion

```
function doSomething() {
   return MongoClient.connect(DB_CONNECTION).then(function(db) {
        myDB = db;
        var collection = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
        var promises = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var innerPromise = collection.update({
               symbol: items[i].symbol
            }, {
               $set: { 
                  value: 123
               }
            }, {
                upsert: true
            });  
            promises.push(innerPromise);
        }
        return Promise.all(promises);
   });
}


var promise = doSomething();
promise.then(function(){
    console.log("DONE");
    myDB.close();
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting a promise back from the MongoClient.connect method so why not use that to chain together. I've put a quick sample together below based on your code:

```
function doSomething(db) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var collection = db.collection(COLLETION_NAME);
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            collection.update({
               symbol: items[i].symbol
            }, {
               $set: { 
                  value: 123
               }
            }, {
               upsert: true
           });
        }

        resolve(db);
    })
}

function connectToDB() {
    return MongoClient.connect(DB_CONNECTION);
}

function closeDB(db) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         db.close();
         resolve();
    });
}

connectToDB().then(function(db){
    return doSomething(db);
}).then(function(db){
    return closeDB(db);
}).then(function(){
    console.log("DONE");
    process.exit();
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log('Something went wrong: ' + error);
});
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Good job :)